# Issue reloading cellForRowAtIndexPath - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having an issue reloading my `tableView` when calling from an outside class to start a method and reload the `tableView`

More specifically:

**Here is the call from the outside class:**

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
        impact* myScript = [[impact alloc] init];
        [myScript startProcess:tag];
    }
**From here** it moves to the `impact` class and loads the `startProcess` method:

    - (void)startProcess:(NSInteger)number {
        NSInteger testing = number;
        cellID = testing;
        // MAKE REQuEST TO SERVER
        [self makeRequests];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
      [self.tableView reloadData];
       });

    }
```

This is the `makeRequests` method it calls:

```
-(void)makeRequests
{
    /* GRAB USERNAME TO BE SENT OVER FOR NOTIFICATIONS */
    NSArray *get = [[SSKeychain allAccounts] init];
    //NSLog(@"get%@", get);
    NSString *username = [get[0] objectForKey:@"acct"];
    //if(cellID != 0)
    //{
        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"function": @"populateNotfications", @"username" : username};
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (error)
        NSLog(@"%s: JSON encode error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"test.com/dev/iphone/test.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",
                        [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSData *paramsData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
        [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[paramsData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:paramsData];


        // issue the request
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"%s: NSURLConnection error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

        // GRAB STATUS OBJECT
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
        self.impactsGrabed = [json objectForKey:@"requested_data"];
    //}


}
```

Now from here it will **run my** `tableView` methods as shown below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.impactsGrabed count];
}

- (double) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"timelineCell";
    impactTimelineCell *cell = (impactTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[impactTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell initTimelineCell];

    cell.statusLabel.text = [self.impactsGrabed[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];
    cell.timestampLabel.text = [self.impactsGrabed[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time_post"];

    return cell;
}
```

I have logged every method and every method works until I hit `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where nothing happens than.  Nothing is returning void.  Now heres the thing:

When calling the function `startProcess` from another class that starts the whole process of loading the `tableView cells` it does not work. If I call the `startProcess` method inside the `viewDidLoad` in that file on initiation the `tableView cells` load properly.

**So for example:**

If I place `[self startProcess:1];` within the `viewDidLoad` it works perfect!  If I call `[myScript startProcess:tag];` from the other class, it wont work properly.

What do you guys think the issue is?

Comment: Your problem is probable this, impact* myScript = [[impact alloc] init]; Do you already have an instance of your impact class (it should be Impact BTW, class names should start with a capital letter)? If so, using alloc init just creates a new instance that's not the one you have on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar heres the import of file `#import "impact.h"` and the file has interface of `impact`.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Do you already have an impact controller when you call alloc init in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method, or are you creating that controller for the first time there? Also, where did you make that controller? In a xib or storyboard? All in code?

Comment: Oh, @rdelmar no I am not calling `alloc init` anywhere else.  And controllers are both created in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your controller are already instantiated and on screen, you don't need to instantiate one (and indeed you shouldn't since that creates a new instance that's not on screen).

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
        impact* myScript = self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[1]; // if my script is one of the child view controllers, then this is how you need to access it -- the number might be 0,1 or 2 depending on which one is the impact controller
        [myScript startProcess:tag];
}
```

You can also do this in prepareForSegue -- when your controller is instantiated, all the embedded child controllers will also be, and you can get a reference to them from the destinationViewController property of the segue.

Because this controller is already on screen, it's ok to call reloadData where you do in startProcess.

Comment: Can you give me an example of putting it inside the `viewDidAppear` and where that should be called.

Comment: @DavidBiga, not sure what you're asking for -- you just put [self.tableView reloadData]; in the viewDidAppear: method.

Comment: what I mean is that, is my other code effecting this someway and needs to be changed because when I can the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method and use the `reloadData`, it still does not work for me.

Comment: @DavidBiga, did you change the way you instantiate the controller? I will update my answer to give an example.

Comment: No I just kept it at `impact alloc`

Comment: BTW the file is already being loaded on opening of controller because its one controller with 3 containers that contain separate classes.  And the `impact` is one of the container classes.  So what happens is when a `collectionView cell` is clicked that's where it calls the `startProcess` method.

Comment: @DavidBiga, you mean that controller already exists as one of three you have embedded in container views? I need to update my answer again then.

Comment: so I have a `ViewController` that contains 3 `Containers` and each is linked to a separate `view controller`,`UItableview`, and  `UICollectionView`.

Comment: How can I determine if one is 0,1, or 2?

Comment: @DavidBiga, log self.childViewControllers, and see what order the array is in.

Comment: @DavidBiga, are you logging inside your view controller that has the 3 container views?

Comment: It is because the class that is being called in is one of the children views.

Comment: @DavidBiga, put the log in the viewDdiLoad method of the controller that has the 3 container views.

Comment: So where I am doing the call to the `myScript` that is where it is calling from and that file is one of the children classes.

Comment: @DavidBiga, ok, I understand now -- let me update once again. But you should still put the log where I said to see what order the childViewControllers array is in.

Comment: Here is the output: `"<AFDetailViewController: 0x10c167c00>",
    "<impact: 0x10c16d0f0>",
    "<UIViewController: 0x10c170000>"`

Comment: @DavidBiga, yeah, ok, so then the number should be 1 right? The impact controller is at index 1.